# What to do with chicken scraps

Tags: chicken

I just bought and cooked a whole chicken in the oven and I'm wondering if there is anything I can do with the scraps left over from slicing up most of the meat. Thank you!

Comment: Make a basic chicken soup and add the bits to that.

Comment: chicken fried rice!

Answer (score 10):

Make stock: Take the entire carcass, brown it in the oven, put it in a pot with some carrot, onion and a bay leaf. Cover with water, bring to the boil and let simmer for an hour or so. Then you can strain it and reduce if you like.

Comment: And I would use the strained liquid in a soup or something similar?

Comment: You could use it in any situation where it calls for chicken stock or broth.

Comment: Also, you don't _have_ to brown the carcass. It tastes better that way but you don't have to. And if you do not have all the ingredients listed you can just skip some of them. In fact, if you just take the chicken carcass as it is and boil it in plain water for a while you will get a perfectly usable stock. But if you do the browning and add the other items it will be even tastier.

Answer (score 2):

You should check this site here: [Chicken Leftover Recipes @ AllRecipes.com](http://allrecipes.com/recipes/everyday-cooking/everyday-leftovers/chicken/).

They've got tons of ideas.. I especially like leftover chicken in quesadilla, quiches, salads, casseroles, and stir fry.

Edit: If the "chicken scraps" you are talking about are mostly bones, chicken stock is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Chicken salad is a nice use for leftover chicken pieces.  (Just be sure to check carefully for small bones!)

The internet or any general cookbook should have a variety of recipes for chicken salad.  My favorite includes halved green grapes and green onion.